# Multiple SVG radial gradients

Tags: svg

How to put multiple SVG radial gradient to an SVG element. A fiddle that i have created for this http://jsfiddle.net/4p9CK/.

I tried the following options but with no success.

```
 - <rect x="20" y="20" width="100" height="100" style="fill:
   url(#center_origin),url(#center_origin2); stroke: black;"/>

 - <rect x="20" y="20" width="100" height="100" style="fill:
   url(#center_origin, #center_origin2); stroke: black;"/>
```

Comment: What do you want it to look like?

Comment: i want a copy of the radial gradient which is on the top left also to be on the bottom right

Comment: So why not create 2 rects, one with a gradient top left and the other bottom right?

Comment: i'm just learning SVG after a long time. I want to know is it possible in SVG to apply multiple backgrounds in a given element (as in CSS3).

Comment: You could via a filter I think. Probably easier in CSS3 though.

Comment: @RobertLongson <![CDATA[ rect{ background-color:red; } ]]> is not working. Is it possible to apply CSS property background to an SVG element?

Comment: You could ask that as a question :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. SVG doesn't support multiple paint servers on one element (a "paint server" is a gradient, pattern etc).  You would need to use multiple elements and simulate your desired effect by using opacity or filters - or by splitting up your shape geometrically.

Comment: SVG 1.1 doesn't support multiple paint servers directly indeed. SVG2 on the other hand, might, see http://www.w3.org/2013/06/03-svg-minutes.html#item10.